# python 3.6.6 input not returning anything from a input

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code is very simple at the moment

```
#BlackJack

print("welcome to Wasteful's blackjack game")`
print("this program was built using standard python")

print("please select a option")
print("A to start, B to quit")
print("----------------------------")

menu_select = input("A/B: ").lower

if menu_select == "a":
    print("starting game when i can be assed to program it")
elif menu_select == "b":
    exit()
else:
    print("invalid")
```

But it returns blank for both `a` and `b`? I'm stuck and could use a bit of help, thanks!

edit: i noticed the stupid error in .lower it should of been .lower()

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are not calling `lower()`, you are setting `menu_select` to the *function itself*:

```
>>> menu_select = input("? ").lower
? 
>>> menu_select
<built-in method lower of str object at 0x10ca5eab0>
```

Change your line to:

```
menu_select = input("A/B: ").lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    print("welcome to Wasteful's blackjack game") 
    print("this program was built using standard python")
    print("please select a option") 
    print("A to start, B to quit")
    print("----------------------------")
    menu_select = input("A/B: ").lower()

    if (menu_select == "a"):
        print("starting game when i can be assed to program it") 

    elif (menu_select == "b"):
        exit() 

    else: 
        print("invalid")

main()
```

First just like rassar said, you must call .lower() after you get your input from the user.
Next, I always find it easier to create a main loop function to call all of your future functions in and keep the code nice and neat! Hopefully this helped a bit!
Happy coding! :)